# Maps represented as bit flips

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be a finite sets and let $F:S\to S$ be a map. Is there a reprensentation of $F$ in terms of (finite) bit sequences, $S\ni x\Rightarrow (\delta_1,\delta_2,\dots,\delta_i,\dots,\delta_n)$, such that $F(x)\Rightarrow (\delta_1,\delta_2,\dots,1-\delta_i,\dots,\delta_n)$.

If this is not true for all maps, are there well known requirements/algorithms for this to happen?

EDIT: The mapping of $S$ into $\mathbb{Z}^n$ need not be one-to-one, as in such a case, statement is definitely not true (just take a constant $F$).

EDIT: I went back and forth on this, but as it was pointed out, $F(x)\ne x$ is a necessary condition.

Comment: What's unclear in your notation is whether *which* bit is flipped can depend on $x$.  What you mean, I think, is that there exists a bitwise representation, $M:S\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n}$, such that $d_{H}(M(F(x)), M(x))=1$ for all $x\in S$, where $d_{H}$ is the Hamming distance (# of bits that differ).  You could change the index $i$ to $i(x)$ if that's really what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly necessary that $F(F(x))=x$ for all $x \in S$.  A map satisfying this condition is called an *involution*.  Moreover, you also have $F(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in S$ (since the bit representations of $x$ and $F(x)$ differ), so $F$ cannot have any fixed points.  These two necessary conditions are also sufficient.  Say that $x \sim y$ if $x=y$ or $x=F(y)$; then there are $|S|/2$ equivalence classes of size $2$.  Given $n$ bits (where $2^n \ge |S|$), you can use $n-1$ bits to label the equivalence classes and the last to label the two elements in each one.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the conditions of the problem so that we don't worry about fixed points. However, bit flips do not form an equivalence relationship, as you can have $(1,0,0)\thicksim(0,0,0)\thicksim(0,0,1)$, but (1,0,0) and (0,0,1) cannot be related through a single bit flip.

Comment: I got confused again, what happens when you have quite a few points mapped to the same one? That point will in turn belong to a coset, so you need to make sure that the bit flip is consistent with how you define the coset representation?

Comment: Thanks... my answer applies to the case where the index of the flipped bit is constant, as your notation seemed to imply.  I think this problem is much harder without that restriction!